# Picard Iteration Given IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the IVP 
$$ x' = (1 - e^x)(x^2 + x - 2)^{(7/9)}, \ \ x(0) = 0, \ \ t\ge 0. $$
Write the formula of the Picard Iteration $\{\phi_n(t)\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ associated with this IVP.

Comment: I'm confused about how to reach the general $ \phi_n $

Comment: What is the IC?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct initial condition.